# 120 mm fan connected directly to power supply?

Tags: troubleshooting, power-supply, fan

Has anyone tried this before? When i bought my 120mm fan, it came with a power adapter to connect directly to a plug that powers IDE drives. So i installed my fan using the adapter to power it and then my computer wouldn't turn on. The power button on PC case just keeps flashing. I have a feeling that this incident just damaged my power supply. Even after i unplugged my fan. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you were working in the case, make sure that all the components and power cables are seated securely.  I've been known to bump surrounding components when working in the confined spaces of a computer case.  Also, if the power supply has a 110/220 switch, make sure it didn't get changed accidentally.

You said that the power button flashes.  Does it flash only after you press the power button, or does it flash whenever the main power cord is plugged in?  Does it flash with any pattern, or is it random?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't unusual for fans to be connected directly to the power supply. Does the computer turn on when you remove the fan from the power supply? There may be a short in it, but it's nigh impossible to tell from here ;-)

Comment: @ burnt1ce: as you may have noticed, i edited your OP because of inapropriate language. i do have sympathy for your frustration, but please refrain from using such language here, i have your comment flagged.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you connect the fan to the original power source?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the power supply and now the computer works, even though the defected power supply works on other computers but just not mine.